# proper use of <figure> and <figcaption> for seo

Tags: html, seo, figure

I want to know how to properly use these two tags.
can I nest text tags like p tag or h1 tag inside figcaption or figcaption will lose its effect ??

```
<figcaption> <h2> some title </h2> </figcaption> //good or bad ??
```

in one scenario I have a card which has image on its right side and some information on left means image and title of image are not inside same div ... in this case what is the best way to add figure,figcaption ??

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="img-container"> <img src="someSrc" alt="someAlt" /></div>
    <div class="info-container"> <h2 class="name">some name</h2> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this W3 link which provides a simple explanation of concerned element - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp

For your first question, I don't see any issue if you are to put additional text elements inside the figcaption element.  Some folks even, define their own CSS style for figcaption.